# how do I get the unique values from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

```
var years = this.api().columns(2).data().toArray().sort();
console.log(years + " before uniq");
var duplicateFreeYears = Array.from(new Set(years));
const uniqueTopicList = _.uniq(years)
console.log("||" + duplicateFreeYears + " after duplicateFreeYears||");
console.log("||" + uniqueTopicList + " after uniqueTopicList||");
```

My data before uniq and after are the same.

```
2016,2016,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015 before uniq


||2016,2016,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015 after duplicateFreeYears||


||2016,2016,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015 after uniqueTopicList||
```

I am still getting the same data

Comment: `_.uniq()` returns the duplicate-free array. It does not modify the original.

Comment: First stop: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#uniq It **returns** the new array of non-duplicates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [lodash.uniq do not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45662804/lodash-uniq-do-not-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function gives you a duplicate version of your updated array.

You have to display this duplicate array :

```
var duplicateArray = _.uniq(years);
console.log(duplicateArray + " after uniq");
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a workaround for that by converting it to a set then an array again:

```
Array.from(new Set(years));
```